# Can someone please clarify this code?

Tags: c, function, memory, stack

I have a doubt in the very basics of C .

- I have written the following code. Here in the `add()` function, I'm not returning anything and so I expected that the output will be some junk value or something, but it didn't happen like that. Can anyone explain to me why it was happening like that? Please excuse me if I have written something wrong in the code.
- To my understanding, I thought the memory for variable `add1` will be from stack and hence once the `add()` is done , all the memory allocated will be freed, thus some junk value will be displayed.
- My clear doubt is without returning anything, how can it print the correct value?

Code sample:

```
main() {
    int x = 4, sum;
    int n;

    printf(" enter a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    sum = add(x, n);

    printf(" total sum = %d\n", sum);
}


add(int x, int n) {
    int add1 = 0;

    add1 = x + n;

    //return(add1);
}
```

Comment: This is Undefined Behaviour. It is not really productive to try and understand exactly what is going on. Whatever behaviour you are seeing is not predictable - it could change depending on the OS, compiler, other (even unrelated) code in the program, etc.

Comment: what compiler is used? gcc fails to compile this code
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'add' with no type [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Evgeniy: It is useless to state what a different language does. C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: Non-prototype function declarators are deprecated (and will hopefully be disallowed by the next version of the standard). Also your compiler should yell at you. Warnings exist for good reasons! Enable them and resolve them before asking others (unless they are the reason to ask, of course)! How about reading a good book? Your question is about basics explained in every C book.

Comment: http://ramblings.implicit.net/c/2014/04/20/c-is-not-a-try-it-and-see-language.html

Comment: @Olaf Are they really? No more implicit `int func()` if the function declaration is missing?

Comment: @2501: Deprecated does not mean disallowed. They are obsolescent features. And the standard requires a warning. I'm too lazy right now to search for you. Feel free: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html. Note that `int f()` is not a correct prototype declarator either.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for ur time and thank u for ur valuable and wonderful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior.

When you don't specify what a function returns, it will default to int. Then when you don't have a return statement, it will be undefined what happens. So in principle anything may happen.

For `gcc`, it will on many system just return some "random" value. In your case it just happens to be the sum. Simply by "luck".

Always turn warnings on during compilation, e.g. `gcc -Wall` and always treat warnings as if they were errors.

Your code should look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x,int n);      // Corrected

int main(void)   // Corrected
{
    int x=4,sum;

    int n;

    printf(" enter a number \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    sum = add(x,n);

    printf(" total sum = %d\n",sum);

    return 0;     // Corrected
}


int add(int x,int n)      // Corrected
{

    int add1=0;

    add1 = x+n;

    return add1;      // Removed the // to uncomment and removed unnecessary ()
}
```

Comment: You try to define how **undefined** behaviour behaves. It is pure speculation if there is a "random value" returned or nasal daemons appear. There are also other problems a standard compliant compiler **has to** warn about.

Comment: Yes bro, Ur edited code will work fine, I got it, but My question Will it return something randomly even if you dont put any return statement ? Ideally, It should not return any thing right, that too, Stack will free the memory for add1 right and hence the value will be lost know. I got confused. can u pls explain it bit more clearly?

Comment: @t.purnaChander - On most systems a simple function like this will return the value by placing the value in one of the CPUs registers. This is system specific and documented in the ABI. The code in `main` will just read that register and treat it as the return value. It doesn't matter whether the function actually wrote to the register or not.

Comment: @olaf - Correct, updated the answer to make it clear that it is undefined.

Comment: @t.purnaChander: The C languages does not mandate a stack. Please differentiate between language and a specific implementation. Anyway, your conclusings are wrong. Read what **undefined behaviour** means (in C); it is a vital concept! Briefly, the compiler is free to generate code wiping your hard drive (well, it will not, but just because that would require specific code). (And please use a more formal language, this is not a school yard).

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a function. Using parenthesis on the expression is deprecated. It is missleading and prone to typos.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, this is undefined behavior, and you shouldn't rely upon it.

However, there is some logic behind what is going on. The return value for a function is, by convention, stored in the `eax` register on x86, or the `rax` register on x86_64. It just happens that your compiler is also using the `eax` or `rax` register for storing the calculated value. Also, since the return type of `add()` is not specified, it is implicitly defined as `int`.